# Removing text contained in brackets/parentheses from corpus (R)

Tags: r

I have a corpus of many documents, containing long texts. I want to tokenize this corpus for further analysis, however, the texts contain irrelevant data within parentheses (typically references, such as:"(example example)"), so I want to delete them.
I have found methods on stackoverflow for text objects, however, I don't know how can I apply this for a corpus (words between the parentheses would be considered as independent tokens and not removed by regex?). I've figured out that I should do it before I remove punctuation (as the latter also removes parentheses).

Could you help me with this? Thank you in advance!

I only reached the regex: "\(*.*\)"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really experienced with R, I try to create one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all texts in brackets using `gsub()`. As you plan to remove the punctuation in a next step, you can replace them with `.`, just to indicate where something was taken (if you need to debug the pipeline) or you can replace them with an empty string `""`.

Your regex would not work. You need to escape the brackets with double back-slashes and you will want to remove multiple, but as few as possible, characters. You'll need the regex `*?` for the contents of the brackets:

```
corp = c("This is an example (or demonstration) of replacing things in brackets",
         "Just use gsub (a function in base) to remove (or better replace) these elements")

corp = gsub("\\(.*?\\)",".",corp)
```

The example above would result in the vector:

```
> corp
[1] "This is an example . of replacing things in brackets"
[2] "Just use gsub . to remove . these elements"
```

Depending on the package you use for your corpus, you can do this with the character vector before converting it to a corpus or you can use specific mapping functions (e.g. `tm_map()` in `tm`) to apply it to all texts.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin! Your proposed solution seems to be working and this was a great help for me! I cannot upvote you yet as a new user, but I would :)